# packaging base64 png with client-zip js

Tags: javascript, base64, zip, png

I am trying to package several png data in base64 format.

The code runs on the client, and it is supposed to generate a zip file for download with png files. The code below works fine except that all the png in the zip are "corrupt".

I gather that they are not in the right format when they are passed to the client-zip. Though I have not been able to find how to convert and pack them in the right way, also including the metadata as in the text examples I found online.

What is the right way of converting and packaging these files?

Staring the obvious, below, each variable `content` holds a string of the form:

`"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA..."`

```
function addImageData(index){
    let fileName = "file_".concat(timePoints[index].concat(".png"));
    let content = o.png();
    snapshotArray.push({ name: fileName, 
                        lastModified: new Date(), 
                        input: content });
}


async function downloadMyZip() {
    const blob = await downloadZip(snapshotArray).blob()
    
    const link = document.createElement("a")
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    var today = new Date();
    link.download = "images_".concat(today.toString()).concat(".zip")
    link.click()
    link.remove()
  }
```

Comment: `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA...`  is a data URI containing a base64 string with png data. You can't just store it in a .png file. To get a valid png file you would need to decode the base64 string (starting directly after .`..base64,`) and save the resulting binary data to a file.

Comment: Thanks! ```window.atob``` seems to do the job with some tweaking.

Comment: If the PNG comes from a Canvas, then you should export the PNG as a Blob directly instead of going through base64. It will save time, memory, and code. This may help: https://github.com/Touffy/client-zip/issues/25